# Multiple citations in single bracket

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

In my report I want to write multiple citations in one bracket, i.e.

> [1-5]

but `\cite{ref1, ref2, ref3}` results in

> [1,2,3]

I am using `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography` to add my bibliography.

When I write `\usepackage{cite}` in the preamble, it is shows an error.

[image: Image showing my code]

[image: Image showing my output]

Comment: `\printbibliography` suggests you are using `biblatex`. In that case you will want to have a look at `style=numeric-comp` instead of `style=numeric`.

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please consider adding an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) is a short document that shows the relevant code from your document so that it can be copied, pasted and run by other people. [Because there are often several ways to do things in LaTeX it is often crucial to know more about your setup](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864) and an MWE is the easiest way to tell us about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex`'s default style `style=numeric` shows each cited item individually. If you want to compress the citations to "[1-5]", you need to load

```
style=numeric-comp
```

See also §3.3.1 *Citation Styles* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the style example for [`numeric`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/30-style-numeric-biber.pdf) and [`numeric-comp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/31-style-numeric-comp-biber.pdf).