# how do I fix my citations to appear in a single bracket?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, multiple-citations

I'm facing this issue where I'm listing my citations as

```
\cite{citation42,citation23}
```

but it still appears in my latex output file as :

```
works [42], [23] ....
```

but it should be  `works [42,23] ....`

How do I fix this? I am using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{cite}
```

I've tried removing the `cite` package and nothing changes.

Referred to this: [Multiple citations in single bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437562/multiple-citations-in-single-bracket)

Not sure why in this instance it refuses to be grouped in a single bracket. Please help, thank you!

edit:

Adding the other packages that are used as well

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Edit 2:

Example to copy paste (it works I checked, just that the problem still persists)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
    
    \title{Exploring the reason why my latex wont work for bibs}
    
    \maketitle
    
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        Recently, this is the abstract i am testing 
    \end{abstract}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    This is how we do the introduction and thus how things are donee in works \cite{citation42,citation23}  like this.
    
    \section*{Acknowledgment}
    
    This project is funded by abcedergrfgsdfg
    
    
    
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{00}
        
        
        \bibitem{citation42}
        L.Writer
        \newblock Large scale benchmark 
        \newblock testestest
        
        
        \bibitem{citation23}
        L.Writer
        \newblock Large scale benchmark 
        \newblock testestest
        
    \end{thebibliography}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always here, you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Sometimes users neglect to tell us about special packages or classes that needs special care, and thus we waste a lot of time.

Comment: Wrapping a simple document around your code gives the expected result, so there is something you are not telling us.

Comment: @daleif I've added in the rest of the preamble, including the IEEE command that came with the template. hope that helps? the document class is conference `IEEEtran` :) thanks!

Comment: That is still not a complete example. We cannot copy that and test it. There is not document class and there is no `\begin/end{document}`.

Comment: See for example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/3929 as to what a good example is. For example you had not mentioned anything about IEEE at all.

Comment: @daleif  thanks for the example! I've pasted a skeleton for you to test out :) thanks for the share! the skeleton works, I tried it out on my end

Comment: just that it still has the same issue with the citation not being combined

Comment: Note that `\cite` combination is not allowed in `IEEEtran` either follow their guidelines or use a different class. `IEEEtran` contains explicit code to `to separate citations with "], ["`

Comment: oh I see! then how do I combine it? @daleif

Comment: You don't. As I said if you have been asked to use the IEEEtran class then you follow their guidelines and stop changing the format they have decided on. Or you use a different document class where you are free to do what you want. This might be annoying to you, but see it from the receivers side: It is super annoying to have to hand edit contributions because the authors did not follow the guide lines. Been there done that, it is time consuming and a waste of everyones time.

Comment: @daleif Got it, thank you for the time to explain! :)  appreciate it!